# Pass Jquery function parameter into a PHP function as part of dynamically controlled dropdown options

Tags: php, ajax

I'm having a problem when trying to dynamically control the options available in a second dropdown when a certain option in a parent dropdown is selected. The value of the option selected in the initial dropdown is not passed into a PHP function which retrieves the applicable options from a database. I'm new to PHP and ajax so only know a few options to try but so far unable to solve.
The value of the initial dropdown options are 1 to 63. I've tried making the PHP function parameter name the same as the ajax function parameter name and tried combinations of PHP variables but a value of '0' is passed into the PHP function instead of 1 to 63  so the 2nd dropdown is populated with the wrong options every time.

The parent dropdown uses an Ajax function which is called on change of option selected:

```
<select onchange="getOptionValues(this.value)">
```

Here is the ajax fucntion:

```
function getOptionValues(project)
{
$.ajax({
    url: 'subtypelist.php?project=' + project,
success: function(data) {
$("#subtype").html(data);
}
});
}
```

This calls `getSubTypeOnProjectID()` (in a PHP class file) and processing PHP file (subtypelist.php) with `getSubTypeOnProjectID()` parameter same as the ajax parameter.

```
function getSubTypeOnProjectID($sub) {
$sql= 'SELECT EST_Index as ID, EST_Text as TEXT FROM EventSubType where EST_EventType = 2 and EST_ProjectID = ?';
return $this->openSql($sql, array($sub));
}

$subTypeList = $thisEventDB->getSubTypeOnProjectID(project);
foreach ($subTypeList as $option)
echo '<option value="'. $option[ID]  . '">' . $option[TEXT] . '</option>';
```

I know that the correct value is being passed to the subtypelist.php via the URL subtypelist.php?project=10 but option value "0" is retrieved instead so it's more like subtypelist.php?project=0. How can I pass the `project` parameter value into the `getSubTypeOnProjectID()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to access the param using `$_GET['project']`, change this:

`$subTypeList = $thisEventDB->getSubTypeOnProjectID($_GET['project']);`

Comment: Ideal answer @Ali ! I wasn't aware of $_GET [``] until now so thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do this:

- every option has a value in the select, from 0 to 63 right?
- create jQuery event for selecting(click, focus) option, adding option value to select

Or even better, I think its possible to get the selected value of the select by just $('input[name="project"]').val()